# ios6 / NSJSONSerialization / and json array data without key/value pair

Tags: objective-c, json, ios6

I'm using a JSON datasource but without key/value pair, and the data is like this:

```
[["user1",1,1,1,1],
["user2",1,1,1,1]]
```

If I try to decode this with `NSJSONSerialization` I get an `NSArray` with 1 entry like this:

```
jsonArray : (
        (
        "user1",
        1,
        1,
        1,
        1
    ),
        (
        user2,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        1
    )
)
```

Any idea how I can get this more usable?

Comment: isn't it still usable by accessing based on array index? elaborate what you mean by 'more usable'

Answer (score 1):

You say "I get an NSArray with 1 entry like this ..."

No, you get an array with two entries, each of which is, itself, an array.

So let's say you had:

```
NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
```

If you want to get the first array, you could then refer to `results[0]`:

```
NSArray *firstResult = jsonArray[0]; // or [jsonArray objectAtIndex:0]
```

Then, if you want to get the first item of that array (e.g. "user1"), you could then

```
NSString *user = firstResult[0]; // or [firstResult objectAtIndex:0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Json elements in array is still equally usable as NSDictionary- Access them using `objectAtIndex` property of NSArray.